# Add Documents to Windows 10 Desktop without shortcut link

Tags: windows-10

How can you add a Documents link to Desktop w/o the shortcut arrow? Last year I had found an application to achieve this and used it at work. Didn't track it though and have lost it, yikes. Thoughts?

[image]

Here are some MS refs I have found which are not working:

**Microsoft Refs** (not working)

- [Pin apps and folders to the desktop or taskbar](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-desktop-shortcut-for-an-Office-program-or-file-9a8df64b-cd87-4700-95cc-4bc3e2a962da) (8/16)
- [Create a desktop shortcut for an Office program or file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-desktop-shortcut-for-an-Office-program-or-file-9a8df64b-cd87-4700-95cc-4bc3e2a962da) (11/14)
- [How to Re-create a Missing "My Documents" Icon on the Desktop](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-desktop-shortcut-for-an-Office-program-or-file-9a8df64b-cd87-4700-95cc-4bc3e2a962da) (6/14)

*I am using Win10 Home v1703

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the following lines to Notepad, and save the file with a `.reg` extension (example, `documents.reg`)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{D3162B92-9365-467A-956B-92703ACA08AF}]
```

Double-click the `.reg` file to apply the settings.

Press <kbd>F5</kbd> on your Desktop, and you'll see the Documents folder (without the shortcut overlay) on your Desktop.

[image]

Comment: thank you for sharing this! I reformatted a computer today, this works so crisp and quick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a CLSID as the shortcut target.

Create a shortcut with the target `explorer.exe shell:::{450D8FBA-AD25-11D0-98A8-0800361B1103}`

This gives a shortcut without the "shortcut" arrow in the icon.  When I tried it, it doesn't use the same icon you have - but it doesnt have an arrow! :

[image: Documents shortcut without "shortcut" arrow]

Once you know to search for "CLSID shortcut", you can find more CLSIDs for other items on the web e.g. [this one](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3123-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts-list-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: this works for generating the shortcut on my desktop, but the arrow is still there! Thoughts?

Comment: Exactly how are you creating the shortcut - is it right click on desktop -> new -> shortcut, editing the target of an existing shortcut to the value above, or something else?

Comment: R.C. Desktop->New->Shortcut:location="<target string posted above>", Next, Name="Documents"

Answer (score 0):

Back up registry first before below operations. If you want to undo the change, just restore from backup registry.

**How to back up and restore the registry in Windows:**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322756/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows

steps as below:
1.  Open RUN, type “***regedit***” and end with enter to open Registry Editor.

2. Navigate to:
   ***HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer***
3. Right click **Explorer** and select **New** – **Key** – rename it as **Shell Icons**.
   [image]
4. Right click newly added key **Shell Icons**, select **New** – **String Value** – rename it as **29**.
5. Double click **29**, in **Value data** box, enter “***%windir%\System32\shell32.dll,-50***” and save the change.
   [image]
6. Re-start system.

Please note that, above operation will remove arrow from all shortcuts icons.

Comment: thank you for this option eve! As Win32Guy's simple .reg solution below works, I will hold off on your regedit soln here. Thank you for the detail and clear instructions though, very appreciated (especially with manual regedit work!) :)